# iBatis logging log4j - how to get sql id in the log

Tags: logging, ibatis

I have the iBatis log working which prints sql stmt, parameters etc. in the log file.
 However it does NOT print the select id.

For example: `select id="getUserInfo" parameterClass="String" resultClass="String"`

I want to print getUserInfo in the log.
 How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a logging framework or something? I use Log4J logging with a consoleAppender class "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" and a fileAppender class and i have my ConversionPattern set to "%d{ISO8601} %-5p %m%n" and it works perfectly for me.

**Console appender settings**

```
  <appender name="A1" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
     <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
     <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %m%n"/>
     </layout>
 </appender>
```

**MY log4j.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration debug="false" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

  <appender name="A1" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="A2" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="../logs/Server.log"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100MB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="2"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>    
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="A1"/>
    <appender-ref ref="A2"/>
  </root>  

 </log4j:configuration>
```

**Server.log file** - **getXYZQuery**

```
    2013-09-02 15:34:44,230 DEBUG {conn-100087} Preparing Statement:   SELECT X,Y,Z FROM XYZ_TBL WHERE TYPE_ID = 1 ORDER BY SORT_PRIORITY asc  
    2013-09-02 15:34:44,230 DEBUG {pstm-100088} Executing Statement:   SELECT X,Y,Z FROM XYZ_TBL WHERE TYPE_ID = 1 ORDER BY SORT_PRIORITY asc  
    2013-09-02 15:34:44,231 DEBUG {conn-100089} Connection
    2013-09-02 15:34:44,240 DEBUG {pstm-100088} Parameters: []
    2013-09-02 15:34:44,243 DEBUG {rset-100091} ResultSet
    2013-09-02 15:34:44,244 DEBUG Query getXYZQuery 18 ms using LIST (9-wlt.getWorkListTabFilter myPcHost)
    2013-09-02 15:34:44,246 DEBUG SQL_RETURN_CONN: OPERATIONAL_DB returned connection 000000001652311912 (A1/100 I1/40 W0)
```

**getXYZQuery is the select id as in**

```
select id="getXYZQuery" parameterClass="String" resultClass="String"
```

I hope this works perhaps it doesn't send me your iBatis XML file and what logging framework you are using.